# Angular Conditions in [style.width.px]

Tags: angular

I currently have this code:

```
<div [style.width.px]="width1">
  <div>Something here</div>
</div>
```

But I need to put a condition like:

```
<div *ngIf="somecondition then [style.width.px]="width1" else [style.width.px]="width2" ">something here</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: use conditional operator: `<div [style.width.px]="condition?width1:width2">`

Comment: you should put that as an answer :) @Eliseo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [conditional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) expression that will return desired value:

```
<div [style.width.px]="someCondition ? width1 : width2">
  <div>Something here</div>
</div>
```